# boost::threadpool::pool::wait() doesn't stop

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, concurrency, threadpool

I was trying to write some Task-Management class with C++ `boost::threadpool`, `condition_variable` and `mutex`. It seems the program will stop at `boost::threadpool::pool::wait()`, but I don't know why this happens.

```
#include <boost/threadpool.hpp>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

enum {
    Running,
    Stopped,
    Exiting
};

class C {
private:
    int                     m_iStatus; 
    mutex                   m_mtx;
    condition_variable      m_cond;
    boost::threadpool::pool m_tp;
public:
    C() : m_iStatus(Stopped), m_tp(8) {}
    void Start();
    void Exit();
private:
    bool Check();
    void Dispatcher();
};

bool C::Check()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_mtx);
    if (m_iStatus == Stopped)
        m_cond.wait(lk);
    if (m_iStatus == Exiting)
        return false;
    else                
        return true;
}

void C::Dispatcher()
{
    if (!Check())
        return;

    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_mtx);
    // do something...
    cout << "." << endl;

    m_tp.schedule(bind(&C::Dispatcher, this));
}

void C::Start()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_mtx);
    m_iStatus = Running;
    m_tp.schedule(bind(&C::Dispatcher, this));
}

void C::Exit()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_mtx);
    m_iStatus = Exiting;
    m_cond.notify_all(); /* notify those waiting on m_cond */
    m_tp.wait(); /* went wrong here */
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.Start();

    /* wait for a moment */
    Sleep(1000);

    /* then call Exit */
    c.Exit();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `boost::threadpool`? Is there a link to the documentation/library it comes from?

Comment: @sehe I don't actually know what it is... I installed boost by vcpkg on windows. There's a `boost/threadpool/` folder and a `/boost/threadpool.hpp`, and I simply included the hpp in my program, but I couldn't find anything about it in the doc from boost.org, neither in github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enter the wait call while still holding the mutex. This will prevent other thread's from completing their work.

In your particular case, the `m_cond` condition variable is waiting on that same mutex, so the call to `m_cond.wait(lk);` will be unable to return as long as the mutex is still being held by the other thread.

One solution to this would be to relinquish the lock on the mutex between notifying the condition variable and waiting for the thread pool to complete:

```
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_mtx);
    m_iStatus = Exiting;
    m_cond.notify_all(); /* notify those waiting on m_cond */
} // lock on m_mtx gets released here
m_tp.wait(); /* this should run fine now */
```